# First different value in a column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I tried many formulas but I cannot find a solution. I have a column populated with id numbers corresponding to the entrance & exit of people. It means that in this column one ID number could appear several times. I want to make another column populated with the id numbers but each one must appear once. So I can I get the first different value in a column?

For example, from the input in column A, I want column B to contain each value just once:

```
     A      B
1  1000   1000
2  1000   2000
3  1000
4  2000
5  2000
```

How can that be done using a spreadsheet formula?

Answer (score 1):

This formula will create a list of all the unique values from the given range:

```
=unique(A:A)
```

Paste this formula in cell B1.

Comment: Thank you very much Max.

Comment: That's ok! If you don't mind clicking the green check to accept this as an answer I'd appreciate it.